# How can I prove this property of definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I recently came across this property.

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two continuous functions in the interval $[a,\,b]$. Then:

$$\left(\int_a^bf(x)\cdot g(x)dx\right)^2=\int_a^bf(x)^2dx+\int_a^bg(x)^2dx$$
I am unable to demonstrate it, and I can't find a demonstration on the internet either. My [Thomas' calculus book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321185587) didn't help.

I saw this expression wrote on the footnote of an old calculus book (the note was written by someone else, not by the author) and now I'm a bit intrigued about its validity. Does this always hold?

A hint or two will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way this is true in general.  If it is, I'll resign.

Comment: This is not true if $f \equiv 0$ and $ g \equiv 1$

Comment: @Randall I thought the same, this can't be true... Maybe I could try to find a counterexample. My calculus skills are those of an engineer: very limited and nowhere near of a real mathematician knowledge.

Comment: There is an *inequality* that holds, but not an equality here.

Comment: @hardmath Is there an inequality that *always* hold? What would it be? I would say "less or equal than" but I'm unsure of that.

Comment: Treating the functions like vectors, your equation looks like $(a \cdot b)^2 = ||a||^2 + ||b||^2.$   A true statement which is similar is $a \cdot b \leq ||a|| ||b||.$

Comment: Thank you guys, then the equation (with the equal sign) doesn't hold in general, right?

Comment: See the example above, which gave $0=1$ in the equation.